# View Navigation on Blackberry Playbook

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, blackberry-playbook

I'm creating a **pure actionscript 3** mobile project for Blackberry Playbook. One problem I have came across is that there seems to be no inbuilt way to handle view navigation. In flex mobile projects, we have the **spark.components.ViewNavigator** component, but this isn't available on a pure AS3 mobile project.

These two links are both making their own libraries for view navigation...

[viewnavigator-for-as3flash-projects](http://www.riaspace.com/2011/02/as3viewnavigator-viewnavigator-for-as3flash-projects/)

[Support-for-screen-navigation-and-application-session-caching-for-qnx-playbook-apps](http://corlan.org/2011/02/22/support-for-screen-navigation-and-application-session-caching-for-qnx-playbook-apps/)

What is the best way to handle view navigation on a *pure AS3 playbook* app?

Are there any older alternative view models we can use out the box?

**Update**

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import spark.components.MobileApplication;
import spark.components.ViewNavigator;
import views.HomeView;

[SWF(height="600", width="1024", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
public class PureAS extends MobileApplication{

    public function PureAS(){
//      super();
    //  var nav:ViewNavigator = new ViewNavigator();
    //  nav.pushView(views.HomeView);
    //  this.firstView = views.HomeView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my opinion on the matter is that if you're going to create an application for the Playbook, might as well use Flex and its power, flexibility and productivity.  Doing pure AS will give you a slight performance boost, but still not enough to counteract how much more developer friendly Flex is.

With that said, if you really want to implement an AS only version, I would just look at how the ViewNavigator does it and adapt it for Sprites.

Comment: Do you know if there anyway of using flex... but doing it in Actionscript? I realise this is fussy ha

Comment: You totally can.  Just let Flash Builder create the original (root) mxml file and everything from there can be done in AS.  *However*, I do not recommend doing this as you're losing productivity by doing AS.  Trust me, when it comes to views and layouts, mxml is the best tool.

Comment: Ye I know, its my manager wanting the pure AS, I would much prefer MXML. Call me stupid but this is what Im doing: 1. New Flex Mobile Project called PureAS 2. Saving PureAS.mxml as PureAS.as 3. replacing its code with (see updated post)... and I am getting (TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.) is this not normal? (I realise you tried to help me yesterday, but just incase I'm doing something stupid...)

Comment: Frankly, if I were you, I'd bring up your case to your manager about why he shouldn't do this.  I guarantee you that he can't give you one single good answer why not use MXML (and no, him not knowing Flex is not an excuse).  You need to keep the main mxml file, you can do the rest in AS.